# Какие сценарии использования Culture в идентификаторе сборки .NET?

Tags: .net

В идентификаторе сборки присутствую четыре параметра: `имя сборки`, `Version`, `Culture` и `PublicKeyToken`. Пример:

```
AssemblyName001, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=222b273a354b8555
```

C `имя сборки`, `Version` и `PublicKeyToken` понятно. Они используются для однозначной идентификации функционала.

Но вот когда нужно изменять значение `Culture`?

Answer (score 1):

Для того, чтобы указать какая языковая культура используется для написания чисел, дат и прочих культурно-зависимых значений, выражений.

Comment: А в чём технические особенности?

Comment: @MaLS, в смысле, как внутри работает?

Comment: Да. Хотелось бы пример. Это и так понятно что `Culture` связано с культурной зависимостью. Но как это выглядит на практике? Когда нужно изменять значение `Culture`?

Comment: @MaLS, например, для ru-RU у Вас разделителем чисел будет выступать точка, для en-US запятая, для ru-RU в дате порядок будет ччммгггг, для en-US ммччгггг

Comment: Т.е. вы хотите сказать, что если загрузить сборку с параметром `Culture=ru-RU`, то конвертация в функционале этой сборке будет происходить согласно культуре ru-RU, а не согласно значениям культуры выполняющегося потока?

Comment: @MaLS, честно, уже не уверен, только что перечитал MSDN и немного в замешательстве. Я попробую и дам знать.